# What exactly is a "major medical condition"?

Tags: united-states, insurance

So I'm filling out a prequalification questionnaire for life insurance, and it asks: "Major medical conditions? ( ) Yes ( ) No".

What is a "Major Medical Condition"? Is there a list in law, or an insurance-industry standard?

Specifically in Michigan, if that matters.

Answer (score 5):

Under the [FMLA](http://www.shrm.org/templatestools/hrqa/pages/howemployeemedicalabsencequalifiesforfmlaleave.aspx):

a **serious health condition** is an illness, injury, impairment or physical or mental condition that involves inpatient care (defined as an overnight stay in a hospital, hospice or residential medical care facility; any overnight admission to such facilities is an automatic trigger for FMLA eligibility) or continuing treatment by a health care provider

---

Under this definition > [Source](http://www.nap.edu/read/9695/chapter/3#20) (See Pages 19-20)

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

A major medical condition is one that could kill you or cause you to become physically or mentally impaired.

Comment: Let's see, I have an ingrown toenail.  It could become infected with resistant bacteria, leading to gangrene and thence to amputation or death.  I need to check "yes" because of this, right?